# Issues Deploying ROOT Context in Tomcat6

Tags: java, deployment, grails, tomcat6

I'm working on getting an application deployed to the ROOT ("/") context in my Tomcat 6 instance.

Here's what has been done:

- Defined another virtual host (domain.com)
- Created the respective folder (/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/domain.com)
- Set it to auto deploy WAR's
- Set appBase to CATALINA_BASE/domainapps and created respective folder
- Copied `manager.xml` from `localhost` to `domain.com`.

Now I'm trying to deploy into the ROOT context by uploading a `ROOT.war` to CATALINA_BASE/domainapps. This isn't working. I don't get any exceptions thrown, but the stock ROOT page ("It works !") stays up. I have successfully deployed it into another context (by uploading `domainapp.war` and viewing at `/domainapp`), but not ROOT.

Re-reading the [Virtual Host](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) setup it makes reference to CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE. My CATALINA_HOME is at `/usr/share/tomcat6/domainapp` while CATALINA_BASE is `/var/lib/tomcat6`. Which should I be using for what? Currently haven't touched CATALINA_HOME but will try messing with a few things there.

---

A better question might be what is the generally accepted flow taken to setup a new Tomcat instance and deploy an application to the root context.

---

I'm going to remove the virtual host I setup and try simply using `localhost`. Since there is only one domain name this shouldn't be an issue, though I would like to more fully understand what goes into setting up a Tomcat virtual host.

Comment: Have u tried this:http://www.coderanch.com/t/424290/Tomcat/deploy-Root-Tomcat-Website

Comment: @Luis: Yes with no change. A primer on setting up tomcat would be great.